# Error in printing the predicted label in FastText

Tags: python, pandas, fasttext

I'm using the `module.predict` from FastText. According to the [documentation](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html#model-object) the number of labels to show needs to be specified by the `k` parameter. However, in my case it doesn't works and as result I'm having only the label with the highest probability. Here my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import fasttext as ft

# here you load the csv into pandas dataframe
df=pd.read_csv('../input_data/data.csv')

# here you load your fasttext module
model=ft.load_model('../model/model.bin')

# line by line, you make the predictions and store them in a list
predictions=[]
for line in df['subject']:
    pred_label=model.predict(line, k=5, threshold=0.5) 
    predictions.append(pred_label)

# you add the list to the dataframe, then save the datframe to new csv
df[['prediction','value']]=predictions
print(df)
df.to_csv('csv_file_w_pred.csv',sep=',',index=False)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your threshold is 0.5. Only one label can be above that at one time since the probabilities sum up to 1.